# AWS SAM - global variables not exists under process.env

Tags: amazon-web-services, variables, aws-lambda

im having some issues with global variables. I have this in my template.yaml

```
Globals:
  Function:
    Environment:
      Variables:
        DEV: true
```

Then I access those variables in code just with

```
process.env.DEV
```

But the problem is that variable does not exist. Only ACCESS_AWS_TOKEN is there. Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.. everything is a string so... use proper condition.

One of the solutions:

```
process.env.DEV.toLowerCase() === 'true'
```

Comment: Could you please explain your answer in more detail?

Comment: Show an example solution. If using a "true" string is what is needed then show that in a working code example.

Comment: Edited the comment and set it as an answer.